# OSG animation in nftBook ARtoolkit android sample

Tags: artoolkit

I am new to Android NDK and AR development. I am working with nftBook sample. I am able to change the marker and pass my work marker. It is working fine, the animation is playing fine on top of my marker.

But when I changed the osg file and provided my own osg, it is not working. I have .osgt file with animation information. It is working fine in iOS. Couldn't understand what I am missing there.

**I have not changed any thing w.r.t to JAVA code or Native code in the sample. Just changed the values in markers and models.
Also I am looking for documentation on AR and OSG. Couldn't find it. **

Can some one help me please.

Answer (score 1):

The markers and OSG data are loaded only once into the cache assets folder when your app is installed. You need to uninstall and reinstall the android app or change the version code in the AndroidManifest.xml file anytime you make a change to the marker or OSG data.

Regarding, documentation please follow what is specified at this Url -
https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit-docs/blob/master/8_Advanced_Topics/osg_usage.md

For detailed documentation on AR and OSG, the above guides you to check out the source code of the file at this path -
`ARTOOLKIT_ROOT/doc/apiref/arosg_h`

2 files `index.html` and `toc.html` at that path will give you the required documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the documentation links. I have moved out of that project now and got into another.